# Dictionary returns none in spite of key existing in it

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I am loading my dictionary with this in a loop at the beginning of my program.
It contains the below values.

```
{3456: ['TATAMOTORS'], 13404: ['SUNTV'], 3718: ['VOLTAS'], 3499: ['TATASTEEL'], 
5900: ['AXISBANK'], 2885: ['RELIANCE'], 15083: ['ADANIPORTS'], 11287: ['UPL']}
```

As and when I get streaming data, I want to know what is the stock. For egs. if I pass 3718 I should get 'VOLTAS'. The above dictionary is never changed.

My code is as below. Stream_data is json. And token is fetched correctly

```
token=stream_data['response']['data']['sym'].replace('_NSE','').strip()
print(token)
print(imp.dictoftokens)
stock = imp.dictoftokens.get(token)
```

What am I doing wrong? I ried it in console and manually passsed a token and it worked correctly.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Hint: Don't let `print` confuse you. Use `print(repr(thing))`.

Comment: Keys in your dict are ints/numbers, and your token is a string. Try .get(int(token)), or convert your keys to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `token` object is of type `str` but your keys are of type `int`:

Change the type of token to `int` and it should work as expected:

```
token=int(stream_data['response']['data']['sym'].replace('_NSE','').strip())
```